# How to back up Google Keep data

Tags: backup, google-backup, google-keep

How do I back up my Google Keep data?

Is there a way I can download everything in one single large .tar.gz tarball or other contiguousing and compression format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Use [Google takeout](http://takeout.google.com/) and select only Google keep. It will export in the format as shown:

[image]

Compress it any format you want,with the tool of your choice. I use [MiXplorer](https://xdaforums.com/t/app-2-2-mixplorer-v6-x-released-fully-featured-file-manager.1523691/), which can compress in the formats shown:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why do I need the XDA developers tool MiXplorer if Google Takeout does everything? Is it just to view the files once they have downloaded?

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson Google Takeout doesn't compress. Your question asks for a compression, so this answer explains a way to do the compression.